# Mongo find query takes 2 minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I have around 75,000 documents in a collection.

The total size of database is around 45GB.
Of the 75k docs, around 45k are of 900 KB each (around 42 GB) and the remaining docs around 120 KB each.

Each document is mapped to a `custId` ObjectId in other collection, and has a `timestamp`, both indexed.

Now I need to fetch the docs for a particular `custId` for last month.
The count is around 5500 docs. This `custId` has the small docs with size around 120 KB each.

**Following is my query:**

```
db.mycollection.find(
{
    custId:ObjectId("CUST_OBJECT_ID_HERE"),
    timestamp:{$gte:one_month_ago_date, $lt:current_date}
}).sort({timestamp:-1})
```

Still the query takes 2 minutes to fetch all records. Is it because of the number of documents or the size of the larger documents? Is there a way I can fix this?

**NOTE:**
It takes 2 minutes when the query is fired from nodejs. If I fire it on mongo shell, it returns quickly but it might be because its just fetching first 50 records. When I attached `.count()` to the query on mongo shell, it took 2 minutes to return with the count.

**Update:**
**Indexing details:**

```
"wiredTiger" : {
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2396160,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 1138688,
        "custId_1" : 598016,
        "timestamp_1" : 659456
    }
}
```

**Explain Output: (with sort)**

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "mydb.mycollection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "custId" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("CUST_OBJECT_ID_HERE")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$lt" : ISODate("2017-05-15T14:20:04.393Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2017-04-15T14:20:04.393Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "custId" : {
                    "$eq" : ObjectId("CUST_OBJECT_ID_HERE")
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "timestamp" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "timestamp_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "timestamp" : [
                        "(new Date(1494858004393), new Date(1492266004393)]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "timestamp" : -1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "timestamp" : {
                                        "$lt" : ISODate("2017-05-15T14:20:04.393Z")
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "timestamp" : {
                                        "$gte" : ISODate("2017-04-15T14:20:04.393Z")
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "custId" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "custId_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "custId" : [
                                    "[ObjectId('CUST_OBJECT_ID_HERE'), ObjectId('CUST_OBJECT_ID_HERE')]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "test-machine",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.2.12",
        "gitVersion" : "REMOVED_BY_OP"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: it's because of the sort. It's got to load the whole thing, either into memory or hard drive.  Because of the size of the database it's probably loading to the hard drive which is slow.  You could try specifying only the properties you need to retrieve which would make it lighter and might make it fit in memory.  I think it'll also only use 1 index when sorting is used and it'll choose the timestamp index and ignore the custId index.  You could try adding a compound index for custId and timestamp.

Comment: Also use pagination if don't you need a all docs at ones

Comment: what indexes do you have on this collection? have you tried mongodb explain? How does this query perform without sort inside mongo shell?

Comment: @Astro, As mentioned, `custId` and `timestamp` are indexed. Without sort it takes 2 minutes. with sort it adds 29 secs.

Comment: @Love-Kesh, no I need all docs at ones.

Comment: @DushyantBangal - as you can see, the winning plan is using only "timestamp" index, so it selects ALL documents between that time and then it has process one by one and select only those, who has concrete custId. You probably has a lot documents in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this index:

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({custId:1,timestamp:1}, {background:true})
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what index is for!

Create index for timestamp and custId (compound index with both of it would be most efficient) and you are just fine. Because of sorting by timestamp, in compound index, make the timestamp the first one (order matters)

---

This is code for creating compound index in mongo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    //...
});

userSchema.index({timestamp: 1, custId: 1});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = userSchema;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on compound index? As mentioned, I have indexed `custId` and `timestamp`, but not a compound index.
If you can mention how it can be done with mongoose, that would be even better.

Comment: @DushyantBangal Please refer to @Astro answear for create compound (combination of multiple keys) index. Please view Mongoose documentation for Compound Index: `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#Indexes-CompoundKeys`

Comment: @DushyantBangal - compound index is one index that map more fields at once. Basically it is the best option, if you want fast select with all these fields included in query. The inner-functionality is not that easy, but as long as you dont sort it with more than one field and you always search it with all fields in query, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are all totally correct. Just going to put in my 2 cents. This answer depends a great deal on the memory available to you and if the information you need to return is "real time" or the info can be cached in some way.

Mongodb is notorious for memory use. (I like mongodb but memory is the Achilles heel). Second as said above anything you can do to improve on query results **before** the query is made is a big plus in time, reads and core usage. When it comes to a storage of documents you may (or will) find a properly set up Redis cache will help you immensely on lowering response times as well.

Obviously this requires memory and in your case a balance (including load balancing). It is a the proper proper mix of memory, speed and disk usage (even if it is SSD), which will help you balance those query requests against the requirements of the system.

Hope that helps a bit.